# Can I refer to JQuery element whose name is common across multiple pages from main controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Can I refer to JQuery element whose name is common across multiple pages(ie each page is having a `<div id="dateRange">`) from main controller using $rootScope or something.

I am selecting date in all of the pages of my site, up till now every page is having individual daterange setup, there by for every route change there would be need for selecting date again.

I want to update this "dateRange" every time there is changes in one of the pages, so the date remains constant throughout the site.